# Binding Expression: Identifier is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, node-modules

I am new to Angular and I am learning the basics of binding expressions. While trying to implement a new module, I keep getting an error in my html file saying that the identifier is not defined. How do I get rid of this error?

"Identifier 'message' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a memberAngular
"

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.38.1 and Angular 8.2.6; I have already tried placing the script references in the head and different parts in the body; tried changing the name of the module, using single and double quotes, and modifying the controller instance. One thing that removes the error is putting the property in the app.component.ts file; but still, I want it to be the module since no one else gets a similar problem. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong and no tutorial that I have seen addresses this issue.

In the script.js file:

```
<reference path="angular.min.js" />
var myApp = angular.module("module1", []);
myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){
  $scope.message = "hello from the controller";
});
```

In the app.component.html file:

```
...
<body>
  <div ng-controller="module1">
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
  </div>
</body>
...
```

In the app.component.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'proj1';
  message = 'hello';
}
```

Comment: You are mixing both AngularJs and Angular (2+).

Comment: You are mixing angularjs with angular. These are completely different things! Please read the documentation to get a basic understanding of angular. https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: Thank you both for the clarification, I had not realized they were different.

Answer (score 0):

remove script.js and put HTML code in app.component.html

```
<body>
  <div>
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

You're using AngularJS strategy. Try to read Angular Docs and follow it.

Comment: I already referenced the angular documentation, and I already tried putting the code from the script.js in the html file; it still says the identifier is not defined.

Comment: you are mixing angularJS and Angular Its two different things

Comment: Somehow I thought those terms were interchangeable; thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing  angular js (v 1, 1+) with Angular (2, 2+).

The Angular Js uses the `ng-controller` for attaching controller and data-binding to view. But in Angular, the components are used for view and data-binding happens from component while AppModule or feature module holds all modules and includes them in app:

You can just use : `<p>{{ message }}</p>` for binding data.

See [this link for a](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jic3xb) basic example